# how to check audio tag load file complete

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i play audio file using audio tag in html 5
duration of my file is 20 second.
but when i open my page, the duration of audio tag is 14 second.
so i refresh the page. then i can see the duration is change to 14 sec or 20 sec.
i don't know why.
and when the file is not loaded completely, i can't control the player.
i click the play bar,  but not control

in other case, sometimes the file load completely, so i can control currentTime and play().
but often the file is not loaded completely, i can use just play the file only one time, not control it

How to sure the file load completely always?

Comment: i solved it. when i use server for development, loading is not perfect. but when i use real server, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may check using 'onloadeddata', just add a listener

```
<audio onloadeddata="doThisOnLoad()">
</audio>
```